# What is the most effective way of State Management in Enterprise level React Application

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I am totally confused about how to manage the application level state in React.
I have an enterprise-level application frontend that has some data that is used across application.

Should I use Redux or react hooks or my own JavaScript code that manages the state?

Comment: https://albertgao.xyz/2022/02/19/react-state-management-libraries-2022/ Read pros/cons and choose for your project.

Comment: May be you should decide with your internal team and it's opinionated... Not well suits here tmk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to need to share the state across a lot of components then you could use either Redux or useContext hook (more Simpler and easy to understand than Redux).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of data (configurations etc) to be shared by multiple components on different hierarchy levels then I will recommend you to use redux-toolkit